# Cycle lengths with prime denominators

Tags: prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

For a math course I've been playing with the following piecewise recurrence relation,

$$f(x_t) = x_{t+1} =
\begin{cases}
      3x_t & 0 \leq x_t < \frac{1}{3} \\
      3x_t - 1 &  \frac{1}{3} \leq x_t < \frac{2}{3} \\
      3 - 3x_t &  \frac{2}{3} \leq x_t \leq 1.
\end{cases}
$$

When the initial condition $x_0$ = $\frac{1}{p}$, where $p$ is prime, successive iterations lie on a cycle. By brute force checking many primes it appears that all cycles have at most $\frac{p-1}{2}$ elements (rarely some have fewer). With my skills I haven't been able to show (or really get an intuition for) why this is the case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you define what a cycle is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{x\} = x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, for $p$ prime $\ge 5$ and $x_0=  \frac1p$ then by induction $$x_t =\left\{  \frac{(-1)^{e_t} 3^t}p\right\}, \qquad e_t=\pm 1$$

Let $r$ be the least positive integer such that $3^r \equiv \pm 1 \bmod p$, since $\Bbb{Z/pZ}^\times / \pm 1$ is a group with $\frac{p-1}{2}$ elements then

> $r$ divides $\frac{p-1}{2}$

Either $x_r = \frac1p=x_0$ and we have a cycle of length $r$,

Or $x_r=- \frac1p$ which means $x_{r+1} =  \frac3p=x_1$ and we have a cycle of length $r$.